# Webview alternatives?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

So, I am developing an application that uses 2-3 WebView, and the performance hit when the user open them is huge: I can't remove them and use native views to show the data because it was requested to use a WebView, so I was looking for a way to embed a page that was less performance hungry.

Thanks for the help ;)

Example:

webview.xml

```
<Alloy>
    <Window id="webview">
        <WebView id="dynamicWebView" />
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

webview.js

```
$.dynamicWebView.url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
$.webview.open();
```

Comment: Can you add some examples? what exactly is the problem? what have you tried?

Comment: I simply open an url into a WebView, my problem is that when I open a WebView suddenly almost 50 MB of RAM are eaten (checked from the monitor of the Android SDK tool), also the WebView is slower than a browser (eg, Chrome for Android).

Comment: share the code you tried so far

Comment: Added the code into the main comment, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative called Crosswalk:
https://github.com/UniversalAvenue/TiCrosswalk

it brings the latest Chromium to all Android devices (even older ones that don't use the external WebView component). But I'm not sure if that brings you some memory advantages since it's still a webview. But give it a try!

Comment: It seems really nice, tomorrow I will try it, thanks!

Comment: Ok, tried it, and well, it has same serious problem, it only works on ARM 7 devices (so devices with an x86 are left out, and that can be an huge problem), the RAM usage increased about ~30 MB with an empty WebView, when I loaded a page it also used more RAM than the standard WebView, so no, will not use it.

Comment: Ok, good to know! But keep in mind that if you rely on newer Chrome features you have to use it if you want to support older devices. If you find a more efficient component please update the thread!

Comment: I am "lucky" and the site embedded into the webview don't use new Chrome features, but you are right, if I will need in the future to embed a more modern site Crosswalk will be really useful; other things that I found, mining a little on jira I found this issue (https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-17723), maybe in the future there will be some new component; any appcelerator dev can confirm this?

Comment: Little update on the crosswalk module, I had some times to test it better and I discovered that it works also on x86, you just need to add the correct abi (armv7 and x86, I think that it will cover almost every device); the APK became bigger, but man, it is crazy fast, was thinking that our site was slow, I was wrong, it was the standard webview that is slower than a snail; it is a little sad that we can't use a shared crosswalk for now, but also embedded it is totally worth.

Comment: Intel is the main contributor to crosswalk, x86 must be supported well now.